# Home page looks different through GoDaddy

Tags: html, css, hosting

I have godaddy hosting [my website](http://www.wintonbrownmusic.online/index.html).

My website looks fine when I host it locally. However, when I launch it through a web browser:

- the navbar looks smaller
- the font looks smaller
- the icons float right instead of being in the middle.

If you click on my link to go to my website, you'll see that it looks smaller but my other pages look normal. Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 4):

Couple things:

1: If you're developing locally on Windows, for example editing files in a text editor and then refreshing a browser to view the changes, you're likely using the Windows API (which is standard for Windows apps), meaning filenames are case-insensitive. An exception to this would be if you're using a more POSIX compliant system, such as Cygwin.

When you move your files to godaddy's server and view them there, they're running a POSIX compliant http server such as Nginx or Apache, so your filenames are case sensitive. I hope this helps clear things up a little for you.

2: My rep is too low to alter your post, but you need to prune the trailing forward slash from your url:

'index.html/' becomes 'index.html'

Comment: I'm using textwrangler for mac.  I was advised by them to change the file names, which I did to make them lower case but the home page still is messed up.

Comment: Your css and js assets are still 404'ing, which is the http response code for  not found. I recommend opening your site with developer tools and looking at the console to see what is being missed.

Is there any chance you can show me a screenshot of the directory structure on godaddy? if all your filenames are lower case and the includes written in the html files are lower case then you should be ok there so all that leaves is failing to upload then, uploading them to the incorrect places or permission issues.

Comment: Is there a way I can load photos on here?

Comment: Perhaps use an image hosting service such as imgur and link here?

Comment: You need to add 2 folders in the same place as your .html, one called css and one called js and put your css and js files in the relevant folders

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. However, my CSS and JS are in the index.html file. I didn't do separate CSS folders for them. Here's the link to my index.html file http://imgur.com/a/2Pas5 so you can see what I mean. There's like 5 CSS links that link to external files allowing me to add social media icons and fonts. Does that make sense?

Comment: Right but your internal css stuff shouldn't be affected, but look you need to fix this and then see what looks odd: https://imgur.com/a/NT3Ff

Comment: Ok so just add the 2 files? But what would I add to them if my CSS and js scripts are already in the index.html?

Comment: I can't think of an instance whereby internal styles would be affected by uploading to a live server, either I am entirely wrong or your problem lays elsewhere, namely with the external files. When you fix the 404s I'll be happy to continue helping you debug.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I'm still trying to figure out how to solve the 404s. I don't mind adding CSS files I just don't know what I'd add because the <links> containing the CSS don't have the actual CSS code unless they can be found online somewhere.

Comment: If I sent images of my code do you think you could show me where the 404s are coming from?

Comment: No sorry I can't help like that, it sounds like you need to find a webdev who knows what they're doing in all honesty

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks different because the site is getting 404 responses for all the styles and scripts. Check on your browser's console for errors. You have to change the sources or upload the assets to your hosting.